# Parsing only left side on Join

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, left-join

In the following code I want to join the table c_files cf with the result of the seccond query inside the two parentheses (alias x).

```
SELECT f_cl_path f,cf.f_id, 'xx' as jo 
FROM c_files cf 
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT f_cl_path f, f_id, f_workgroup, 'yy' as jo FROM myOtherTable 
     WHERE f_workgroup ='1234' AND f_status<=2) x 
ON x.f_id=cf.f_id  
WHERE cf.f_workgroup='798190' and jo='xx';
```

I'd like to get only elements where `jo='xx'`. But this doesn't work. When I try it with `jo='yy'` I get a result, but I need it with `jo='xx'`.

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs and/or an sqlfiddle TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Comment: jo is an alias for a "constant" with value 'yy' in your subquery. (`'xx' as jo` won't be considered at all). So no, `'xx' != 'yy'`

Comment: Your  alises should be different the last jo is taken by mysql so rename the custom columns to jox and joy

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid the first one won't be considered even if named jox. An alias can't be used in the where clause at the same "level of query".

Comment: @Raphaël Althaus is there an other way to use this alias in the where clause?

Comment: Is this possible with the join? Maybe left join, right join,...?

Comment: Well, try to explain what you really want. As jo seems to be just a tricky way to get something logical...

Comment: I need only the values, which are NOT INSIDE of the parentheses of the LEFT JOIN. I tried to get this with "jo", but is there an way to do it without "jo"? I meant: SELECT f_cl_path FROM c_files cf NOT IN (SELECT...). This join is my alternative to NOT IN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After seeing your comments, maybe this image could be helpful.

[image]

In your case would be something like this if I'm not wrong:

```
SELECT f_cl_path f,cf.f_id
FROM c_files cf
LEFT JOIN (SELECT f_cl_path f, f_id, f_workgroup FROM myOtherTable 
     WHERE f_workgroup ='1234' AND f_status<=2) as x
ON x.f_id=cf.f_id  
WHERE cf.f_workgroup='798190' and x.f_id IS NULL
```